# Implementing an efficient graph data structure for maintaining cluster distances in the Rank-Order Clustering algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to implement the Rank-Order Clustering [here is a link to the paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/efd6/4b7641bea8ca536f4e179be6e2dd25d519d6.pdf) (which is a kind of agglomerative clustering) algorithm from scratch. I have read through the paper (many times) and I have an implementation that is working although it is a lot slower than I expect.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/kevinlu1211/FacialClusteringPipeline) to my Github which has instructions to download and run the Jupyter Notebook.

**The algorithm:**

> **Algorithm 1** Rank-Order distance based clustering
>
> **Input:**
>     *N* faces, Rank-Order distance threshold
>   *t*
>   .
>   **Output:**
>     A cluster set **C** and an “un-grouped” cluster
>   *C<sub>un</sub>*.
>   1: Initialize clusters **C** = { *C<sub>1</sub>*, *C<sub>2</sub>*, … *C<sub>N</sub>* }
>    by letting each face be a single-element cluster.
>   2: **repeat**
>   3:  **for all** pair *C<sub>j</sub>* and *C<sub>i</sub>* in **C** **do**
>   4:   Compute distances *D<sup>R</sup>*(
>   *C<sub>i</sub>*, *C<sub>j</sub>*) by (4) and
>   *D<sup>N</sup>*(*C<sub>i</sub>*, *C<sub>j</sub>*) by (5).
>   5:   **if** *D<sup>R</sup>*(*C<sub>i</sub>*, *C<sub>j</sub>*)
>   < *t* and *D<sup>N</sup>*(*C<sub>i</sub>*, *C<sub>j</sub>*) < 1 **then**
>   6:    Denote ⟨*C<sub>i</sub>*, *C<sub>j</sub>*⟩
>   as a candidate merging pair.
>   7:   **end if**
>   8:  **end for**
>   9:  Do “transitive” merge on all candidate merging pairs.
>     (For example, *C<sub>i</sub>*, *C<sub>j</sub>*, *C<sub>k</sub>* are merged
>     if ⟨*C<sub>i</sub>*, *C<sub>j</sub>*⟩ and ⟨*C<sub>j</sub>*, *C<sub>k</sub>*⟩ are candidate merging pairs.)
>   10:  Update **C** and absolute distances between clusters by (3).
>   11: **until** No merge happens
>   12: Move all single-element clusters in **C** into an “un-grouped” face cluster *C<sub>un</sub>*.
>   13: **return C** and *C<sub>un</sub>*.

**My implementation:**

I have defined a `Cluster` class like so:

```
class Cluster:
    def __init__(self):
        self.faces = list()
        self.absolute_distance_neighbours = None
```

A `Face` class like so:

```
class Face:
    def __init__(self, embedding):
        self.embedding = embedding # a point in 128 dimensional space
        self.absolute_distance_neighbours = None
```

I have also implemented finding the rank-order distance `(D^R(C_i, C_j))` and the normalized distance `(D^N(C_i, C_j))` used in `step 4` so these can be taken for granted.

Here is my implementation for finding the closest absolute distance between two clusters:

```
def find_nearest_distance_between_clusters(cluster1, cluster2):
    nearest_distance = sys.float_info.max
    for face1 in cluster1.faces:
        for face2 in cluster2.faces:
            distance = np.linalg.norm(face1.embedding - face2.embedding, ord = 1)

            if distance < nearest_distance: 
                nearest_distance = distance

            # If there is a distance of 0 then there is no need to continue
            if distance == 0:
                return(0)
    return(nearest_distance)


def assign_absolute_distance_neighbours_for_clusters(clusters, N = 20):
    for i, cluster1 in enumerate(clusters):
        nearest_neighbours = []
        for j, cluster2 in enumerate(clusters):
            distance = find_nearest_distance_between_clusters(cluster1, cluster2)    
            neighbour = Neighbour(cluster2, distance)
            nearest_neighbours.append(neighbour)
        nearest_neighbours.sort(key = lambda x: x.distance)
        # take only the top N neighbours
        cluster1.absolute_distance_neighbours = nearest_neighbours[0:N]
```

Here is my implementation of the rank-order clustering algorithm (assume that the implementation of `find_normalized_distance_between_clusters` and `find_rank_order_distance_between_clusters` is correct):

```
import networkx as nx
def find_clusters(faces):
    clusters = initial_cluster_creation(faces) # makes each face a cluster
    assign_absolute_distance_neighbours_for_clusters(clusters)
    t = 14 # threshold number for rank-order clustering
    prev_cluster_number = len(clusters)
    num_created_clusters = prev_cluster_number
    is_initialized = False

    while (not is_initialized) or (num_created_clusters):
        print("Number of clusters in this iteration: {}".format(len(clusters)))

        G = nx.Graph()
        for cluster in clusters:
            G.add_node(cluster)

        processed_pairs = 0

        # Find the candidate merging pairs
        for i, cluster1 in enumerate(clusters):

            # Only get the top 20 nearest neighbours for each cluster
            for j, cluster2 in enumerate([neighbour.entity for neighbour in \
                                          cluster1.absolute_distance_neighbours]):
                processed_pairs += 1
                print("Processed {}/{} pairs".format(processed_pairs, len(clusters) * 20), end="\r")
                # No need to merge with yourself 
                if cluster1 is cluster2:
                    continue
                else: 
                    normalized_distance = find_normalized_distance_between_clusters(cluster1, cluster2)
                    if (normalized_distance >= 1):
                        continue
                    rank_order_distance = find_rank_order_distance_between_clusters(cluster1, cluster2)
                    if (rank_order_distance >= t):
                        continue
                    G.add_edge(cluster1, cluster2) # add an edge to denote that these two clusters are to be merged

        # Create the new clusters            
        clusters = []
        # Note here that nx.connected_components(G) are 
        # the clusters that are connected
        for _clusters in nx.connected_components(G):
            new_cluster = Cluster()
            for cluster in _clusters:
                for face in cluster.faces:
                    new_cluster.faces.append(face)
            clusters.append(new_cluster)


        current_cluster_number = len(clusters)
        num_created_clusters = prev_cluster_number - current_cluster_number
        prev_cluster_number = current_cluster_number


        # Recalculate the distance between clusters (this is what is taking a long time)
        assign_absolute_distance_neighbours_for_clusters(clusters)


        is_initialized = True

    # Now that the clusters have been created, separate them into clusters that have one face
    # and clusters that have more than one face
    unmatched_clusters = []
    matched_clusters = []

    for cluster in clusters:
        if len(cluster.faces) == 1:
            unmatched_clusters.append(cluster)
        else:
            matched_clusters.append(cluster)

    matched_clusters.sort(key = lambda x: len(x.faces), reverse = True)

    return(matched_clusters, unmatched_clusters)
```

**The problem:**

The reason for the slow performance is due to `step 10: Update C and absolute distance between clusters by (3)` where `(3)` is:

[image]

This is the smallest L1-norm distance between all the faces in `C_i (cluster i)` and `C_j (cluster j)`

After merging the clusters
Since I have to recalculate the absolute distances between the newly created clusters every time I finish finding the candidate merging pairs in `steps 3 - 8`. I'm basically having to do a nested for loop for all the created cluster and then having ANOTHER nested for loop to find the two faces that have the closest distance. Afterwards, I still have to sort the neighbours by nearest distance!

I believe that this is the wrong approach as I have looked at [OpenBR](https://github.com/biometrics/openbr/blob/master/openbr/core/cluster.cpp) which has also implemented the same Rank-Order Clustering algorithm that I want it is under the method name:

`Clusters br::ClusterGraph(Neighborhood neighborhood, float aggressiveness, const QString &csv)`

Although I'm not that familiar with C++ I'm pretty sure that they are not recalculating the absolute distances between the clusters which leads me to believe that this is the part of the algorithm that I am implementing wrongly.

Moreover, at the top of their method declaration the comments say that they have pre-computed a kNN graph which makes sense as when I recalculate the absolute distances between clusters I am doing a lot of computation that I have previously done. I believe that the key is to precompute a kNN graph for the clusters although this is the part that I'm stuck at. I can't think of how to implement the data structure so that the absolute distances of the clusters would not have to be recalculated every time they are merged.

Comment: Have you [searched](https://www.google.com/search?q=A+Rank-Order+Distance+based+Clustering+Algorithm+for+Face+Tagging+github&ie=&oe=#spf=1) GitHub?

Comment: Yes I have looked at the OpenBR library but I can't seem to make sense of what it is doing as I am unable to compile it

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, and this is what OpenBR [seems to do as well](https://github.com/biometrics/openbr/blob/master/openbr/core/cluster.cpp#L333-L356), what is needed is a lookup table for cluster ID -> cluster object from which a new cluster list is generated from without re-calculation.

Can see where the new cluster is generated from an ID lookup table at [this section on OpenBR](https://github.com/biometrics/openbr/blob/master/openbr/core/cluster.cpp#L333-L337).

For your code, will need to add an ID to each `Cluster` object, integers will probably be best for memory usage. Then update the merge code to create a list of to-be-merged indices at `findClusters` and create a new cluster list from the existing cluster indices. Then merge and update neighbours from their indices.

The last step, neighbour indice merging [can be seen here on OpenBR](https://github.com/biometrics/openbr/blob/master/openbr/core/cluster.cpp#L352).

The key part is that no new clusters are created on merge and distance for them is not re-calculated. Only indices are updated from existing cluster objects and their neighbouring distances merged.

Comment: Do you think you could modify my function and implement it? If it works I'll gladly accept your answer. I'm still a bit confused about how to merge/update the clusters. In particular I'm a confused how I would create the list of to-be-merged indices as during the merge the number of resulting clusters would be greater than one. How would I keep track of which clusters are supposed to be merged together?

Comment: A list of to be merged cluster ids should work - that is also what OpenBR does. I do not have the time to do the implementation. There is also sufficient code in OpenBR to use it as a basis for porting to your Python code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to store distance values between faces in dictionary ex.

```
class Face:
    def __init__(self, embedding, id):
        self.embedding = embedding # a point in 128 dimensional space
        self.absolute_distance_neighbours = None
        self.id = id #Add face unique id

distances = {}

def find_nearest_distance_between_clusters(cluster1, cluster2):
    nearest_distance = sys.float_info.max
    for face1 in cluster1.faces:
        for face2 in cluster2.faces:
            if not distances.has_key( (face1.id, face2.id) ):
                distances[(face1.id, face2.id)] = np.linalg.norm(face1.embedding - face2.embedding, ord = 1) #calc distance only once
            distance = distances[(face1.id, face2.id)] #use precalc distances
            if distance < nearest_distance: 
                nearest_distance = distance

            # If there is a distance of 0 then there is no need to continue
            if distance == 0:
                return(0)
    return(nearest_distance)
```